# how to get the row in some column in one table

Tags: postgresql

I have some problem with query in postgresql

I have 7 column in one table

```
Year    Month   Date    Rain    Tmax    Tmin    ID Stat Location
1996    1   1   3   25.4    20  98212   air
1996    1   2   1   25.4    19.6    96112   land
1996    1   3   -9999   24.6    19.2    97110   sea
1996    1   4   1   22  19  98212   air
1996    1   5   -9999   24.4    19  96112   land
1996    1   6   -9999   24.2    18.6    98212   air
1996    1   7   1   24.2    19.4    96112   land
1996    1   8   -9999   24.8    20  97110   sea
1996    1   9   -9999   25  19.6    97110   sea
```

I want to query the row in table and get output to the text file with name (ID-Stat Location)
 the expected output :

```
98212-air.txt

Year    Month   Date    Rain    Tmax    Tmin
1996    1   1   3   25.4    20
1996    1   4   1   22  19
1996    1   6   -9999   24.2    18.6
```

what should I do?
I'm using postgresql.

thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query to get the output like you told but writing in the text file you need to work.

```
  SELECT year,month,date, rain, tmax,timin 
     FROM yourTable  WHERE Location='air' and id_stat='98212';
```

Comment: thank you for the response and answer. I have already do the code. and it works. Actually, I want to take the another result in one query, example : I have 3 ID in the table above. Not just one id_stat=98212.? How can I get the result of them?

Comment: how the query for more one id_stat? example 2 ID_Stat? But, the data is different output. thanks

Comment: can you expalin more? i didnt get it?